# Symfony disable logging does not work

Tags: logging, symfony1, permissions

For my frontend_dev controller I want to disable logging. I did it like this:

```
dev:
  .settings:
    error_reporting:        E_ALL
    logging_enabled:        false
    web_debug:              true
    cache:                  false
    no_script_name:         false
    etag:                   false
    timeout:                1800  # Session lifetime in seconds
    charset:                utf-8
```

But I get an error because symfony still tries to write a log file:

> [25-Feb-2011 09:57:27] Unable to open the log file "E:\approot\framework\log/frontend_dev.log" for writing.

It's not because of the slash, when I set the permissions it works.

(And yes, I cleared the cache.)

The funny thing about the problem is, that sf can write into the cache folder but not into the log folder, I didn't touch any folder permission settings, not locally and not live (IIS).

**Edit:**

I can now disabled logging completely by setting sfNoLogger in the factories.yml.
But then the web debug toolbar disappears[ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5119955/symfony-web-debug-tool-bar-disappears-when-using-sfnologger).

Comment: Odd. I still get things in my frontend_dev.log if I turn logging off, too. It reduced down to something that looked like web debug info, though, so I turned that off. And now with both `web_debug` and `logging_enabled` set to `false`, it _still_ creates a log file. Just with nothing in it. I'm with you; this seems a bit weird.

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me.

Comment: @Blair Although it's odd that it doesn't happen with the production environment. Either it's a bug, or there's something we're missing turning off. I don't suppose this gets tested much, as of course there's no value whatever in doing it -- the logs are half the point of the dev environment, so turning them off is something hardly anyone would ever want to do...

Comment: @Matt True. But you would think that turning off the logging should stop it trying to write a file. I would expect that you *should* be able to have file logging off and the web_debug bar on.

Comment: @Blair Yes, agreed. I guess that the web_debug bar hits an error when trying to display its logging section when there's a no-op logger in place, and that that is a bug, and that nobody's come across it yet because it's such a contradictory situation. And I imagine the real answer here is "find out why you can't write to your log file and fix *that*", not "battle through freaky edge-case Symfony bugs so you can avoid writing log files in your dev environment." Especially as you'd have to debug it without a logfile and a debug bar!

Answer (score 0):

Id be willing to bet that below your dev snippet you have

```
all:
  .settings:
    logging_enabled:        true
```

move this all block to the top of the file.