# Symfony web debug tool bar disappears when using sfNoLogger

Tags: debugging, logging, symfony1, factories

Why does the web debug tool bar disappear when I use sfNoLogger in the factories.yml:

```
dev:
  logger:
    class:   sfNoLogger
    param:
      level:   err
      loggers: ~
```

When I remove these lines the tool bar appears.

Answer (score 0):

[Because the sf**No**Logger does **not log** anything](http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/sfNoLogger). It's usually used for production.